# After filter-branch ing to remove file from git repo, file remains in pack file

Tags: git

I have added and subsequently removed a binary file (path `"ACHThesis/preamble.fmt"`) from my git repository using the method as outlined in [Update a development team with rewritten Git repo history, removing big files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4444091/git-filter-branch-to-delete-large-file) . As suggested by the gitbook I also ran

```
rm -Rf .git/refs/original
rm -Rf .git/logs/
git gc
```

Indeed, the large file no longer appears to be referenced by any commits, as shown by

```
git log --pretty=oneline -- ACHThesis/preamble.fmt
(no output)
```

However, when I look at the biggest file in the repository with

```
git verify-pack -v .git/objects/pack/pack-6136e671bba3772bdf40ba3306aa249d654
0a117.idx | sort -k 3 -n | tail -1
e4cf847b6815c9833d04f9a449286112718a3926 blob   6771554 2414394 6791333
```

and look at its identity

```
$ git rev-list --objects --all | grep e4cf
e4cf847b6815c9833d04f9a449286112718a3926 ACHThesis/preamble.fmt
```

the binary file is clearly still present. **How can I remove it ?**

---

Questions I have looked at but which have not helped

- [Why do large files still exist in my packfile, after scrubbing them with filter-branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10656794/why-do-large-files-still-exist-in-my-packfile-after-scrubbing-them-with-filter)
- [How to remove unused objects from a git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3797907/howto-remove-unused-objects-from-a-git-repsitory)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Short Answer

The file will go away on its own eventually. It will never be sent over the network since it is no longer reachable from any of your branches. If you can live with the disk space for a while, leave it alone.

## Medium Answer

`git clone` the repository to another location on disk and `rm` the original repository.

## Long Answer

[See this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2164581/remove-file-from-git-repository-history).

Answer (score 0):

I think `git gc` only remove objects older than 2 weeks by default. Maybe you can try to rerun it with the `--prune` option

```
git gc --prune=now
```

Comment: I ran this as well as some of the other commands in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10656794/why-do-large-files-still-exist-in-my-packfile-after-scrubbing-them-with-filter as well, file persists.

Answer (score 0):

The "solution" that I ended up with was to clone the repository after I had performed all the `filter-branches` -- the cloned repo did not have the removed binaries upon packing.

I am sure there is a better solution, though, so I shall leave this as 'unanswered' for a couple more days in the hope someone git-savvy comes along.